# Unable to establish connection. using DBeaver apache phoenix to connect to Apache Hbase database

Tags: jdbc, hbase, dbeaver

I have a standalone Apache HBase Database installed on an ubuntu vm,
i want to be able to connect to the db from the outside using dbeaver (Apache Phoenix)

the Master is up and i am able to use the database inside the vm

[image]

when testing

[image]

i get this error :

[image]

> ERROR 103 (08004): Unalbel to establish connection.
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptoin
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> InvocationTargetException
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    'void
> sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong(java.lang.Object, int, long)'

My hbase-site.xml :

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>./tmp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

<property>

    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>

    <value>file:///home/azureuser/HBASE/hbase</value>

</property>

<property>

   <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>

   <value>/home/azureuser/HBASE/zookeeper</value>

</property>

<property>
     <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
     <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hope someone can help or guide me through the right direction

Comment: I would start by checking 
1.wheather port 2181 accessible from the outside
2.try and connect using dbeaver from within  the VM to see if anything is wrong with Dbeaver

Comment: that's exactly what i did when i couldn't connect

Comment: and what were the outcomes of the above two steps that you performed..
was port 2181 accessible from outside? were you able to connect using dbeaver within the VM?

Comment: the port is accessible and no i couldn't connect within the vm using dbeaver

Comment: I get this error when I try to connect to HBase `1.4` using driver for HBase `1.5`.